# In Android, can I change the width of a view inside a widget at runtime

Tags: android, widget

I have a 4x1 widget that holds several `ImageView` views inside a `LinearLayout`. I want to be able to have. I want to be able to adjust the width of those views depending on the screen resolution of the device where the app is installed. My goal is to have each view be the same width, and to have them uniformly distributed across the width of the widget. And I'd like it to fill up the whole width of the widget (so that if the widget covers more space on high resolution devices, each `ImageView` would be wider). I don't want to create different XML layouts for each device type (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc) -- I'd like to have this done programmatically when the widget is set up (or updated). But I can't find any documentation in `RemoteViews` that allows me to change the width of a view. So is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to do it at runtime.

You can use the `android:layout_weight` tag in your XML file. If you set the weight to `1` and set each image to `0dp`, the images will be the exact same width. That way you won't need to create different layouts for each screen size.